# Process that locked file

Tags: macos, cocoa, macos-carbon, core-foundation

Im trying to identify the processes that have a text file locked.

Im looking to do this with Carbon or Cocoa please.

I am new to MacAPI, I come from WinAPI.

Thanks

edit: added corefoundation tag as i hear carbon is deprecated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check which process is using a file by running the command `lsof` e.g.

```
lsof | grep file.txt
```

From the manpage of `lsof`

```
The  mode character is followed by one of these lock characters, describing the type of lock applied to the
              file:

                   N for a Solaris NFS lock of unknown type;
                   r for read lock on part of the file;
                   R for a read lock on the entire file;
                   w for a write lock on part of the file;
                   W for a write lock on the entire file;
                   u for a read and write lock of any length;
                   U for a lock of unknown type;
                   x for an SCO OpenServer Xenix lock on part      of the file;
                   X for an SCO OpenServer Xenix lock on the      entire file;
                   space if there is no lock.

              See the LOCKS section for more information on the lock information character.
```

Comment: That will list all the processes that could have locked the file, but will it say which one actually has the lock?

Comment: Check the manpage. It mentions about lock. I added it to the answer

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Although the OP seems to be looking for an API solution, not a CLI. I realize he could use `popen()` to run `lsof`, but then he has to parse the output.

Comment: BTW, wouldn't `lsof file.txt` be better than using `grep`?

Comment: Thanks much for the effort to answer. Yes Im looking for API solution so i can sort through the processes and focus the application that has the text file locked please.